# BigQuery SQL optimization - Why larger table first in JOIN?

Tags: google-bigquery

The YouTube [Strategies for optimizing your BigQuery queries - JOIN pattern](https://Strategies%20for%20optimizing%20your%20BigQuery%20queries) says.

> Make sure to place the large table first in JOIN

But Why? I read somewhere to place the smaller driving table first is better so that the set of the join keys to go through becomes smaller, but apparently it is not the case here.

Please explain what it the rational.

Comment: The reverse order would make sense if the larger table had an index on it and the query were sargable.  But BQ doesn't support indices.

Answer (score 1):

@TimBiegeleisen's comment is correct. And in addition, it is Google's best practice to put **larger table on the left and smaller one on the right** when using `JOIN` because it creates a **Broadcast JOIN** wherein it

> sends all the data in the smaller table to each slot that processes the larger table.

This optimizes the query since the data from the smaller table are already distributed to each slot of the larger table which is then processed per slot.

You may refer to this [BigQuery - Optimizing JOIN Patterns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns) documentation for more details.

Comment: Broadcast JOIN means sending the smaller table data to each slot if smaller table fits in the memory of the slot but I believe it is not always the case?